# How to continue if element is not find - Scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, try-catch, except, nosuchelementexception

I'm scraping a page that is basically a search engine. A sheet that has some client codes (called CPF) send keys to the page then it gives me some info, witch I'm scraping to that sheet. The scraping code Is almost done, but I'm can't deal with wrong client numbers.

The page works like this:

1- If the client code is ok, the page redirect and show some infos that I can already scrape;

2- If the client code does not have all numbers, the "search" button do nothing;

3- If the client code has all numbers but It have something wrong, the page shows a popup.

In cases 2 and 3 I wanna print something (CPF Invalido) and go to the next client code. Here's the code I already have:

```
        for cpf in self.cpfs:
        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")

        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        self.delay = 3  # seconds

        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
        age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
        beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
        concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
        salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
        bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
        bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
        bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
        bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
        bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
        bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/h2')))
            print('CPF Valido')

            print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('CPF Invalido')

        nomes.append(nome)
        idades.append(age)
        beneficios.append(beneficio)
        concessoes.append(concessao)
        salarios.append(salario)
        bancoss.append(bankslist)
        bancoscard.append(bcardlist)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

    return nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards
```

I'm using the try with an element of the page that is showed when the client code is right, so the except NoSuchElementException should print CPF Invalido and continue the code, searching for others client codes.

In case 2 the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MOISA/PycharmProjects/inss2/cpf_updater.py", line 47, in <module>
    cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
  File "C:/Users/MOISA/PycharmProjects/inss2/cpf_updater.py", line 32, in process_cpf_list
    nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\k_bot.py", line 66, in search_cpfs
    nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2
```

In case 3 it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MOISA/PycharmProjects/inss2/cpf_updater.py", line 47, in <module>
    cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
  File "C:/Users/MOISA/PycharmProjects/inss2/cpf_updater.py", line 32, in process_cpf_list
    nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\k_bot.py", line 66, in search_cpfs
    nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: Nenhum benefício foi localizado para este CPF.
```

Here's the cpf_updater

```
    def process_cpf_list(self):
            cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

            bot_url = BOT(cpfs)
            try:
                nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
                print("Atualizando...")
                for i in range(len(nomes)):
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.age_col, idades[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[i])
                        self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.card_col, cards[i])

            except NoSuchElementException:
                print('CPF Invalido')
                pass

cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. As it stands, you have already handled if the element is not found with your try except. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sri! The problem is that if the client code is wrong (cases 2 and 3) it gives an error

Comment: What error does it give you Moises? It has occured to me you might also get a TimeoutException you should handle. Because you are waiting for the element, rather than finding it. You will likely get a TimeoutException rather than a NoSuchElementException

Comment: I'v updated the post with them

Answer (score 0):

For case 2:

You get a NoSuchElementException on line 47 of cpf_updater.py. You should encase the relevant section in a try except, and handle NoSuchElementException.

For case 3:
On the same line, you should also handle UnexpectedAlertPresentException.
This exception usually occurs when you get a modal, or some popup, or an alert.

I am not entirely sure which line corresponds to line 47 of cpf_updater.py, but that is where the problem stems.

Edit: It seems like you need to place the following in a try except for the above two exceptions. The error is caused in the function call in the first line I think. And the resulting variables are dependent on that call.

```
nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()

        print("Atualizando...")
        for i in range(len(nomes)):
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.nome_col, nomes[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.age_col, idades[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.salario_col, salarios[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.consig_col, consigs[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.card_col, cards[i])
```

Comment: Great Sri!! I kinda undestand what I should do, but not exactly how... I'v added the cpf_updater to the question so If you could help me

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I't worked, but now I'm getting through a Infinite loop :( I'v update the cpf_updater to the question

Comment: I don't think you need the while(True) statement. That without a break will never exit. Additionally, continue goes onto the next iteration of the loop. Break is what exits the loop. But since it will only run once anyways, you don't need the while loop

Comment: I'm new with programming, sorry for my nooby questions... While statement was the only way I could add continue to the code. Without continue or with pass the code stoped

Comment: No problem Moises. We all start somewhere, I'm by no means an expert. Are you able to determine why the code stops without the while loop? Since the function does not return anything, I am wondering what the caller is doing.

Comment: Thanks Sri, appreciate that! Actually It's not giving an error, but If the client code is wrong (cases 2 and 3) the code stops (with or without pass statement). I'm trying to make It work with your help and some search, them I found that with a continue statement it doesn't stop, but for the it work properly had to add while statement, witch made the loop infinite. Without while the continue is outside of a loop.

Comment: Hmm, so with the current code you have, it stops immediately in Case 2,3? Can you post the function that calls process_cpf_list()?

Comment: It's not that on the last line of  the last code of my question?

Comment: Oh I see. My apologies. Okay, so from what I understand, you call process_cpf_list() once. It does not find the element, and does not make any changes to the sheet. After that, what is expected to happen?

Comment: I expecte that It goes to the next item on the list. The first collum of the sheet has all the client codes, some of them right and some wrong (cases 2 and 3). If its right, the code works normally, but if one of them is wrong i wanna go to the next one

Comment: Can you point out the list that you are trying to iterate over for me? How does your program know to go to the next item in the list?

Comment: Please take a look at the first lines of the first code of my question and the first lines of the last code of my question

Comment: From what I see, you are looping over the cpfs. If you skip on one cpf, it should go to the next cpf in the loop. I am still a bit confused as to the flow of your program. Are you calling process_cpf_list() for each cpf in self.cpfs?